# XAML Designer never shows my properties in the Properties window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a custom WPF UserControl.

I can drag one or more of them into any xaml in the project.

It can be manipulated via the Properties Window in the same way other WPF graphical elements can  be.

But the class has a public BitmapSource property that never shows up in the properties window of the XAML Designer, so I end up having to set it in code behind after the ui loads.

So how do I get my custom properties -- of whatever type -- to appear in there?

Comment: it will be easier to understant your problem to have the source code of items...

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for other graphical elements, but still not for UserControl:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public BitmapSource HoverSource { get; set; }
```